# How to define the template priority between built-in categories and custom taxonomies?

Tags: template-hierarchy

Let's say I want to create a custom template for my taxonomy `customtax`.

This is pretty simple, I just create a `taxonomy-customtax.php` in my theme directory.

Now, I'ld like to query a built-in category with one term of my custom taxonomy, like so:

```
www.example.com/?customtax=x&category_name=y
```

The problem here is that Wordpress always uses the `archive.php` (or `category.php` I think) instead of my `taxonomy-customtax.php` template.

Is there a way to invert this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *tell* WordPress what template file to use with the [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) hook.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse98738_taxonomy_redirect' );
function wpse98738_taxonomy_redirect() {
    if( 'x' == $customtax && 'y' == $category_name ) {
        include( get_template_directory() . '/taxonomy-customtax.php' );
        // if you're using a Child Theme, use the following line instead:
        // include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/taxonomy-customtax.php' );
        exit; // so that WP quits looking for templates to load
    }
}
```

#### Reference

Codex pages for:

[`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect)

[`get_template_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory) / 
[`get_stylesheet_directory()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory)